# Finding periodic orbits the system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the periodic orbits the following system of differential equations?
$$\begin{cases}x'=y\\y'=-\frac d{dx}V(x)\end{cases}$$
where $V(x)=b(1-\cos x)$, $b>0$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't it the equation of a pendulum? It does not admit closed form solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This equation describes a mathematical pendulum, and it does not admit closed form solutions. Nevertheless, you can easily obtain the **shape** of the periodic orbits in phase space by noticing that this system is conservative. The quantity that is conserved during motion is of course the energy (as this is a physical example), yielding

$$E\equiv\frac{1}{2}y^{2}+V\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}y^{2}+b\left(1-\cos x\right)\equiv\rm const.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt}=y\\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac d{dx}V(x)=b\sin(x)\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b\sin(x)}{y}$$
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=b\sin(x)\quad\to\quad \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=-b\cos(x)+c_1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{c_1-b\sin(x)}$$
$$y=\pm\int \sqrt{c_1-b\sin(x)}\:dx$$
Equation of the trajectory :
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{c_1-b}\:\:\text{E}\left(\frac{x}{2}\:\big|\frac{2b}{b-c_1} \right)+c_2$$
Elliptic Integral of the second kind.